# What is Blackhole & what caused it in CakePHP Security?

Tags: cakephp

Hi I have read this manual but I still didn't understand the terms : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html

I also search on google regarding blackhole in security but what I got is just blackhole in networking.

What is actually blackhole in CakePHP security?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"request blackholing" means the intended controller action won't be executed and instead an exception will be thrown by the SecurityComponent resulting in an error page.

Comment: P.S. Unless you are working on an existing project you should be using CakePHP 3.1 :)

Comment: Thanks boss for the explanation!